# How to understand the integral of $f(x)$ on the interval $[a,b]$.

Tags: calculus, integration

If I visualize in integral, I imagine it the way I was always taught: as the area under the curve described by $f(x)$, on some interval $[a,b]$. For this area it should not matter whether we integrate from $a$ to $b$ or from $b$ to $a$, the value should be the same.

However, using the fundamental theorem of calculus,

$\int_{b}^{a}f(x)dx=F(a)-F(b)=-[F(b)-F(a)]=-\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$,

with $f(x)=\frac{dF}{dx}$.

Is there some better way to visually or conceptually understand an integral instead of "the area under a function", that makes more sense in this aspect?

Comment: The integral gives an oriented and signed area, which depends on the values of $f$ (signed) and and an orientation of your domain. If you integrate on $[a,b]$, where $a<b$ you have a positively oriented domain, if you integrate from $a$ to $b$ and your integral gets a sign if you integrate from $b$ to $a$.

Comment: See this answer for a better view of integrals rather than simply viewing them as areas.  Areas are an *application area* of integrals, not their fundamental idea.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4048155/how-do-integrals-add-up-all-the-areas-within-their-bounds/4048811#4048811

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to appreciate the distinction that you are making, you have to get a little algebraic. The integral is unfortunately not totally understandable in an intuitive and visual way. Loosely speaking, the integral is the limit of rectangles under the graph, so we can look at the approximation using rectangles to see how it affects the resulting integral.

[image: Integrating from a to b]

We *define* integrating from a to b as partitioning the interval $[a,b]$ from left to right, so that $x_{i-1}<x_i$, therefore, that factor of $(x_i-x_{i-1})$ is positive.

If we then look at $b\to a$
[image: Integrating from b to a]

using the same reasoning, we see that $(x_i-x_{i-1})$ is negative. Therefore, $f(x)(x_i-x_{i-1})$ has the opposite sign depending on the direction of integration.

So really, the issue is about consistency of definition more than anything. Hope that helps!